# MariaDB: Access Denied after every reboot

Tags: mysql, mariadb, reset

Im using a MariaDB on raspberry pi 3 (raspbian), and i have root user with a specific password

***Problem***: When i reboot the raspberry, i get *access denied for user root@localhost*

I did reset the root password with *mysqld --skip-grant-tables* and i flushed privileges. then i restarted the server.

After that, when i type *sudo mysql* i get logged in without asking for password.

When i reboot the raspberry again, i get access denied for user root@localhost again.
Once more i switched into the skip-grant-tables thing, and looked into the mysql.user table, but the password was set correctly!

what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Is the commandline tool `mysql` running on raspberry pi?  Or does it need to go across TCP/IP.  In the latter case, "localhost" is _not_ the client machine.

Comment: yes, mysql is run via commandline (i just use a remote desktop). it does not need to go via tcp/ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be due to MariaDB's mechanism for authenticating users(root) based on Unix sockets [(as explained here)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/). Try running this query:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE user = 'root' AND plugin = 'unix_socket'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then restart MariaDB.

Comment: thanks for the hint, did not work though. i also deleted folders /etc/mysql and /var/mysql and reinstalled mariadb, resulted in same behaviour.

Comment: Are you using ssh to connect to RPi ?

Comment: i spent some time trying, the issue was indeed that it authenticated only via unix socket, *although* the plugin column is empty in the users table.
i cant get standard password authentication to work, but at least i can use it now. 
accepted for best answer since the hint was correct, thanks a lot.